# Get field name in SAP GUI

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I'm trying to get this field name in SAP GUI:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subBLOCK:SAPLKACB:1015/ctxtCOBL-KOSTL")
```

I have the following code, to check each object in the given screen:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SAPfields()

    Dim sapguiauto As Object
    Dim sapapp As Object
    Dim sapcon As Object
    Dim session As Object
    Dim Area As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Children As Object
    Dim Obj As Object

    Set sapguiauto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set sapapp = sapguiauto.GetScriptingEngine
    Set sapcon = sapapp.Children(0)
    Set session = sapcon.Children(0)
    Set Area = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr")
    Set Children = Area.Children()

    For i = 0 To Children.Count() - 1
        Set Obj = Children(CInt(i))
        Debug.Print Obj.Name
                
    Next i
    Set Children = Nothing
    Set Obj = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

When I print the object names, I get this:

```
subBLOCK:SAPLKACB:1015
```

What should I do to get the exact field?

I tried to use below code but it did not work:

```
OBJ("subBLOCK:SAPLKACB:1015").Children()
```

Answer (score 1):

On my system (SAP front end version 7400.3.13.3369), executing your code gives me the field name, but it is not fully qualified.

E.g. Here's selection criteria from a SQVI screen on my system.

[image: selection criteria from a SQVI screen on my system]

Running your procedure with this screen visible, I get the following:

```
%BS02000_BLOCK_1000
%_SP$00001_%_APP_%-TEXT
SP$00001-LOW
%_SP$00001_%_APP_%-TO_TEXT
...
```

You can simply change your code to display the `Obj.ID` as shown below to get the fully qualified path to the field name.

```
...
debug.print Obj.ID
...
```

This gives

```
/app/con[0]/ses[0]/wnd[0]/usr/box%BS02000_BLOCK_1000
/app/con[0]/ses[0]/wnd[0]/usr/txt%_SP$00001_%_APP_%-TEXT
/app/con[0]/ses[0]/wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSP$00001-LOW
/app/con[0]/ses[0]/wnd[0]/usr/txt%_SP$00001_%_APP_%-TO_TEXT
...
```

If you want to get the text displayed on the screen, use `.Text`:

```
...
debug.print "Name=" & Obj.Name & "  Value=" & Obj.Text
...
```

```
Name=%_SP$00001_%_APP_%-TEXT  Value=Plant
Name=SP$00001-LOW  Value=
Name=%_SP$00001_%_APP_%-TO_TEXT  Value=to
Name=SP$00001-HIGH  Value=
Name=%_SP$00001_%_APP_%-VALU_PUSH  Value=
...
```

FYI, to get the field name of a data element that currently has focus, as ScriptMan suggests, you can use the script below.

```
Sub GetSAPObjectID()
    '-Variables---------------------------------------------------------
      Dim SAPGUI 
      Dim App 
      Dim Con 
      Dim Ses 
      Dim ActID 

    Set SAPGUI = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    If Not IsObject(SAPGUI) Then
      Exit Sub
    End If

    Set App = SAPGUI.GetScriptingEngine()
    If Not IsObject(App) Then
      SAPGUI = Nothing
      Exit Sub
    End If

    Set Con = App.Children(0)
    If Not IsObject(Con) Then
      Set App = Nothing
      Set SAPGUI = Nothing
      Exit Sub
    End If

    Set Ses = Con.Sessions(0)
    If Not IsObject(Ses) Then
      Set Con = Nothing
      Set App = Nothing
      Set SAPGUI = Nothing
      Exit Sub
    End If
    ActID = Ses.ActiveWindow.SystemFocus.ID
    Debug.Print ActID

    Set Ses = Nothing
    Set Con = Nothing
    Set App = Nothing
    Set SAPGUI = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the SAP GUI script recorder. Then you can see the recorded script.

Comment: It does not help if I want to loop through al the fields.

Comment: In any case, the following should be possible: Obj.setFocus or Debug.Print Obj.Text